# Restoration of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find complex function $f(z)$, such that
$$
|f(z)|=e^x(x^2+y^2).
$$
I may guess that $ f(z) = z^2 e^{z+i \alpha}, \text{Im}\, \alpha = 0 $. But how to prove that there is no other functions?

Answer (score 1):

You have 
$$
\lvert f(z) \rvert  = e^x (x^2 + y^2) = \lvert e^z z^2 \rvert
$$
If you are looking for *holomorphic* solutions (in some domain) then it follows that
$$
 \frac{f(z)}{e^z z^2}
$$ 
is holomorphic with constant modulus. The maximum modulus principle (or open mapping theorem) implies that the quotient is constant, so that
$$
 f(z) = c e^z z^2
$$
for some complex number $c$ with $\lvert c \rvert = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider for instance $f(z) = \vert z \vert^2 e^z$, or even $f(z) = e^{\Re x}(\Re z^2 + \Im z^2)$.

Comment: You mean, that there may be lots of functions?

Comment: Sure. You just require something on the modulus of the function, so if $f$ is such a function, the function $fg$ for any function $g$ such that $\vert g \vert = 1$ will work ! It might be another story if you require more regularity, for instance if $f$ must be an entire function.

Comment: Yes, I see. There I forgot to say that $f$ is analytic function. Does that change anything?

Comment: Yes because you can show that if two functions $f$ and $g$ are entier such that $\vert f \vert = \vert g\vert$ then $f=\alpha g$ for some $\omega  \in \mathbb C$ such that $\vert \omega  \vert = 1$. To see that, one has $\vert f/g\vert =1$ so $f/g$ is bounded thus by Liouville theorem ($f/g$ is holomorphic because the singularities are removable) it is constant: $f/g=\omega $ and the condition $\vert f/g\vert =1$ implies $\vert \omega  \vert = 1$. It is your condition with $\omega = e^{i \alpha}$.